# Evaluate $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}$ $1 \over \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ $dx$

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

> I would like to evaluate
>
> $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}$ $1 \over \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ $dx$

**Approach**

We substitute $x = \sin u$ $\Rightarrow$ $dx \over du$ $=$ $\cos u \Rightarrow dx$ $=$ $\cos u$ $du.$

This leads to

$\int_{\sin(-1/2)}^{\sin(1/2)} 1$ $du$ = $[u]_{\sin(-1/2)}^{\sin(1/2)}$ = $[\arcsin(x)]_{-1/2}^{1/2}$

Now, my calculator tells me that the result would be $1$, but this doesn't work with my solution that I got so far. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: ...and if further evidence is needed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(%5Csqrt(1-x%5E2))+between+-1%2F2+and+1%2F2...

Comment: $\pi$ is indeed away from $3$ by $0.141592654...$ but $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is away from $1$ by $0.04...$. Does your calulator understand something about $fixing$ digits shown?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct. The final result should be :

$$\arcsin(1/2) - \arcsin(-1/2) = \frac{\pi}{6} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3} = 60^{\circ}$$

Comment: Well, then my calculator was wrong. It looks like one can't rely one them when the integral becomes a little bit harder. :D Thank you!

Comment: \arcsin looks like $\arcsin$ in math form :-)

Comment: Although I agree with your calculation, I must ask why you have 60${}^\circ$ in the final step. What does the integral have to do with that angle?

Comment: @mickep Yes you're right. I added the value in degree because I suspected the OP had some problems with the angle unit on his calculator.

Comment: No, I simply chose the wrong integration limits, it was my mistake. Now the calculator gives me indeed $\pi \over 3$. :-)

Comment: Indeed the result of the integral is a real number, not an angle, hence the answer $\frac\pi3$ is correct while the answer $60°$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the calculator here?
$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2\arcsin\frac{1}{2} = 2\cdot\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}.$$
Anyway, I doubt you calculator uses the approximation $\pi\approx 3$!

Comment: $\pi =3! = 6$ would indeed be a rather concerning approximation. ;-)